# UUID parameter mapping not working with Hibernate 6

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, uuid, hibernate-6.x

I have the following example code:

```java
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Example> query = builder.createQuery(Example.class);
final Root<Example> root = query.from(Example.class);

query = query.where(
        builder.equal(
                root.get("id"),
                builder.literal(UUID.fromString("2c8aa259-323d-4a92-bf4c-03c68e5753ce"))
        )
);

for (final Example example : entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList()) {
    System.out.println(example);
}
```

This used to work perfectly fine with Hibernate 5, though after upgrading to Hibernate 6 I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: select e1_0.id from example e1_0 where e1_0.id=2c8aa259-323d-4a92-bf4c-03c68e5753ce

jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : JDBC exception executing SQL [select e1_0.id from example e1_0 where e1_0.id=2c8aa259-323d-4a92-bf4c-03c68e5753ce]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:374) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:987) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:405) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M6.jar:6.0.0-M6]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy79.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.example.Main.lambda$runner$0(Main.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M5.jar:3.0.0-M5]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select e1_0.id from example e1_0 where e1_0.id=2c8aa259-323d-4a92-bf4c-03c68e5753ce]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.lambda$processNext$0(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advance(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.3.Final.jar:6.1.3.Final]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "c8aa259"
  Position: 47
```

Basically the query generated is invalid. I am using PostgreSQL 14.

I used to have `hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode: inline` though this was also updated in accordance with Hibernate 6 to `hibernate.criteria.value_handling_mode: inline`.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I just created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15590 for this